# HTML <a> tag changes url but doesn't move browser location

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm working on a web development project using AngularJS and PHP. I have this line of seemingly trivial HTML:

```
<p><a href="products.php">Back to All Products</a></p>
```

This link is within the file products.php and appears only when a query string is present, which causes Angular and PHP to load products by category.

For some reason when I click the link it creates, the URL of the page changes but the page doesn't load, and the page content doesn't change. Even more bizarre, when I click the browser's reload button, it loads products.php. But the strangest part is that there's another link on the page that has the same link, and functions properly!

Providing an absolute link rather than relative fixes the problem, but does anyone have some idea why this would be happening?

Comment: looks to be because it has the extension `.php` - where the angular routing doesn't use the extension and the route setup is likely just `products`. Ultimately, if you don't have a `products.php` route then angular doesn't know what to do with the page

Comment: I don't have any routing set up at all, so I don't see why it would be interfering. Is there a default functionality which would cause this sort of issue?

Comment: you sure the html for `<a>` is well formed? Symptoms sound very strange. Provide demo that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl the line you see is exactly as it exists in my code. I'll see if I can make a demo.

Comment: I tried to make a Plunker for this issue, but there the link is working properly, even directly copied and pasted from mine. That said, it doesn't seem to handle php files very well, so I don't know how representative it is of my situation.

Comment: Why are you using angular??

Comment: It's job is to intercept navigation to serve up views/templates based on the navigation. Seems to me you're using the wrong tools.

Comment: @Darren More like using the tools wrong. I'm new to it. Thanks.

Comment: @Darren so is that reason enough for it to be acting up? Considering I don't have routing set up I figured it wouldn't be such an issue. And I've used links inside of ng-apps before without issue so I'm not sure what's different here.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well, the solution was to add the `target` attribute with value `_self`

```
<p><a href="products.php" target="_self">Back to All Products</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Clint's answer but it did not work for me.

Change:

`<p><a href="products.php">Back to All Products</a></p>`

To:

`<a href="products.php"><p>Back to All Products </p></a>`

I faced this issue when there is plain text directly within the `<a> </a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of the context of the tags. Try moving them out of the parent tag. (See if there is a form making it fail)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).